# How do I change the class-path of one of my applications in JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have a JBoss EAP 6.4 implementation which runs a bunch of separate applications within it. All living in the same WAR file.
For one of those applications I want to modify the class-path. Specifically I want it to exchange two jars for two others.

Is that possible?

Comment: I dont think it's possible since they're all in the same WAR, any possibility of separating the particular one out to its own WAR?

Comment: Why don't you use shared jars as custom modules in JBoss EAP?